# Как передавать большие контейнеры между потоками?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qthread

Как передавать большие контейнеры между потоками? Можно указатель передать?
Подводные камни, советы?
Ниже привожу пример.

```
class Data {
    QMap<int, SomeClass> _m;  // большие
    std::array<SomeClass, 1024*1024> _a;
public:
    void initData();
};

class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Data *_d;
public:
    Worker() : QObject() { _d = new Data; }
signals:
    void finished(Data *d);
public slots:
    void process() { _d->initData(); emit finished(_d); }
};

class Controller : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Data *_d;
public:
    Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }
    void start() {
        QThread *thr = new QThread;
        Worker *w = new Worker;
        w->moveToThread(thr);
        connect(thr, &QThread::started, w, &Worker::process);
        connect(w, &Worker::finished, this, [this] (Data *d) { _d = d;});
        connect(w, &Worker::finished, this, &Controller::finished);
        connect(w, &Worker::finished, thr, &QThread::quit);
        connect(w, &Worker::finished, w, &Worker::deleteLater);
        connect(thr, &QThread::finished, thr, &QThread::deleteLater);
        thr->start();
    }
signals:
    void finished(Data *d);
};
```

**UDP:** Возникли сложности с использованием умного указателя: [Умный указатель сигнал-слот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004314)

Comment: У вас сырой указатель и Вы его не удаляете. Это основной подводный камень при работе с сырыми указателями.

Comment: А большие это сколько?

Comment: @Cerbo 1-3 гигабайт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указатель передать можно. Только лучше не "сырой", а "умный". Если планируется использовать большой объект только из одного места одновременно, советую `std::unique_ptr`. В таком случае об освобождении памяти можно не задумываться.

Из подводных камней, насколько мне известно, не будет никаких, если всегда использовать объект только из одного потока. Если планируется "общий" объект, разделяемый рядом потоков, необходимо ознакомиться хотя бы с мьютексами, а лучше вообще с концепциями многопоточного программирования и доступа к данным в нём.

Comment: с умным указателем проблемы из-за удаленного конструктора копирования

Comment: @KtoTo Потому он и unique, что не позволяет себя копировать. Это позволяет избежать его использования из разных мест ввиду наличия копий. Я видел Ваш вопрос на этот счёт, сейчас постараюсь ответить.