# Умный указатель сигнал-слот

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, указатели, unique-ptr

Попробовал передать умный указатель `std::unique_ptr` через сигнал/слот и получил ошибку из за удаленного конструктора копирования (`unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;`). Так можно ли использовать умный указатель `std::unique_ptr` в сигнал/стол? **UDP: нельзя!**
Связный вопрос: [Как передавать большие контейнеры между потоками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004225)

Переделал класс под указатель `std::shared_ptr<Data>`. Используя замечания **@yrHeTaTeJlb**, вызываю: `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::shared_ptr<Data>);` и `qRegisterMetaType<std::shared_ptr<Data>>("shared_ptr<Data>");`. И все заработало.

Вывод **qDebug()**:

```
Data();
finish
~Data();
```

**mainwwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMap>
#include <memory>

class Data {
    QMap<int, QString> _m;  // большие
    std::array<QString, 1024*1024> _a;
public:
    Data() { qDebug() << "Data();"; }
    ~Data() { qDebug() << "~Data();"; }
    void initData();
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::shared_ptr<Data>);

class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    std::shared_ptr<Data> _d;
public:
    Worker() : QObject(), _d(std::make_shared<Data>()) { }
signals:
    void finished(std::shared_ptr<Data> d);
public slots:
    void process() { _d->initData(); emit finished(_d); }
};

class Controller : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    std::shared_ptr<Data> _d;
public:
    Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }
    void start();
signals:
    void finished(std::shared_ptr<Data> d);
};

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Controller _c;
    std::shared_ptr<Data> _d;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QThread>

void Data::initData() { /*some init code*/ }

void Controller::start() {
    QThread *thr = new QThread;
    Worker *w = new Worker;
    w->moveToThread(thr);
    connect(thr, &QThread::started, w, &Worker::process);
    connect(w, &Worker::finished, this, &Controller::finished);
    connect(w, &Worker::finished, thr, &QThread::quit);
    connect(w, &Worker::finished, w, &Worker::deleteLater);
    connect(thr, &QThread::finished, thr, &QThread::deleteLater);
    thr->start();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    qRegisterMetaType<std::shared_ptr<Data>>("shared_ptr<Data>");
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(&_c, &Controller::finished, this, [this] (std::shared_ptr<Data> d) { qDebug() << "finish"; _d = d; });
    _c.start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }
```

Comment: Ты не можешь передать такой указатель с помощью копирования. Только перемещение.

Comment: `void finished(std::unique_ptr<Data> d);` - вот и копирование. Так как конструктор копирование удален, то, при передаче в функцию такого указателя, невозможно передать его по значению. Либо ссылку, что ломает концепцию уникальности, либо указатель, что тоже ломает.

Comment: А как это должно работать если подключить сигнал к двум слотам?

Comment: Для передачи сигналов между потоками исплоьзуется [`Qt::QueuedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). Для того чтобы передавать объекты c `Qt::QueuedConnection` их тип нужно зарегистрировать через [`QMetaType::qRegisterMetaType`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1). Для этого тип нужно сначала объявить через [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE). `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` тредует чтобы у класса был конструктор копирования, а у `std::unique_ptr` его нет

Comment: Если вызывать `connect` с `Qt::AutoConnection`, то он превратиится в `Qt::QueuedConnection` в вашем случае. Для того чтобы передавать объекты c `Qt::QueuedConnection` ... [см. выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004314/%d0%a3%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82#comment1701152_1004314)

Comment: В более общем виде без указания специализации умные указатели регистрируются как `Q_DECLARE_SMART_POINTER_METATYPE(std::shared_ptr)`, а последовательные контейнеры `Q_DECLARE_SEQUENTIAL_CONTAINER_METATYPE(std::array)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию `connect` выполянется с [`Qt::AutoConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Если сигнал передается между потоками `Qt::AutoConnection` == `Qt::QueuedConnection`

Для того чтобы передавать объекты c `Qt::QueuedConnection` их тип нужно зарегистрировать через [`QMetaType::qRegisterMetaType`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1).

Для этого тип нужно сначала объявить через [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE).

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` требует чтобы у класса был конструктор копирования, а у `std::unique_ptr` его нет.

Таким образом передать `std::unique_ptr` через сигнал из потока в поток не получится.